# Can I do pandas dataframe manipulation on the Snowflake engine, instead of snowpark dataframe manipulation?

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am seeing that the Python data manipulation that is possible on Snowflake is Snowpark dataframe manipulation, but not Pandas dataframe manipulation. If I were to convert the Snowpark dataframe to Pandas dataframe, then it looks like that dataframe will be created in my local memory, and whatever pandas manipulation will be done using my local machine resources.

Is it possible to do the pandas dataframe manipulation directly on Snowflake engine without bringing it into my local machine?

Below I show a use case of how I would want to do some pandas manipulation on a dataframe and then write the resulting dataframe into a table in Snowflake. I'm hoping that using a Snowpark session or Python worksheet in Snowsight, I could read the dataframe `df` from Snowflake that looks something like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['short','short','short','short','medium','medium','medium','tall','tall','tall'],'height':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
```

And then do the following pandas manipulation on Snowflake engine (kindly ignore how weird such manipulation is):

```
df.loc[ df.height.isin([1,2,3]), 'height2'] = df['height'] * 2
df.loc[ df.height.isin([7,8,9]), 'height2'] = df['height'] + 2
df['height2'] = df.groupby('category').height2.fillna(method='ffill')
df['height2'] = df['height2'].fillna(df['height'])
```

And then write the final `df` into a Snowflake table.

If it's not possible to do pandas manipulation on Snowflake engine, how do I achieve the above using Snowpark dataframe manipulation? It feels like the Snowpark dataframe manipulation is not as flexible as Pandas..

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, if this helps. But you can use python worksheets in Snowflake UI and perform data manipulations either on pandas dataframe or snowpark dataframes.

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col


def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.
    import functools
    import pandas as pd
    df = session.create_dataframe([("short", 1), ("tall", 10)], schema=["category", "height"])
    df = df.to_pandas()
    #do data manipulation
    #convert pandas dataframe to snowpark dataframe
    dataframe = session.create_dataframe(df)
    return dataframe
```